# Error visual con imagen en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

la cosa es que recientemente cree una sencilla aplicacion en Android Studio.
La cosa es muy simple, es un logo en la parte de arriba, seguida por dos botones.

La cosa es que no se porque en mi telefono se ve un error visual extraño
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que en el dispositivo virtual que tengo tambien asignado a Android Studio, se ve relativamente bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, podria ser cosa de mi telefono? o algun error en el xml de la actividad o imcompatibilidad de los paquetes.
Si necesitan el codigo fuente tambien lo puedo poner.

Gracias.

Aqui el codigo de la Vista

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_c"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arnop_logo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/canalvivo"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/canal_en_vivo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/consulta"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/consulta_tu_plan" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código de la vista?

Comment: @ChristopherVilla Vale, ahi lo agregue a la publicacion.